# Gitlab pipeline failed : ERROR: Preparation failed: Error response from daemon: toomanyrequests

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, docker-in-docker, harbor

I have `Harbor` local docker registry and all needed images are there and connected GitLab to the Harbor and all the images are received from the Harbor but after November 2, Docker put a limit on the number of pulls and it seems dind service pulls from Docker hub.
Is it possible to use dind service to pull from Harbor?

Pipeline output:

```
Running with gitlab-runner 12.10.1 (ce065b93)
  on docker_runner_7 WykGNjC6
Preparing the "docker" executor
30:20
Using Docker executor with image **harbor**.XXX.XXXX.net/library/docker_maven_jvm14 ...
Starting service docker:**dind** ...
**Pulling docker image docker:dind** ...
**ERROR**: Preparation failed: Error response from daemon: toomanyrequests: You have reached your pull rate limit. You may increase the limit by authenticating and upgrading: https://www.docker.com/increase-rate-limit (docker.go:198:2s)
Will be retried in 3s ...
Using Docker executor with image harbor.XXX.XXX.net/library/docker_maven_jvm14 ...
Starting service docker:dind ...
Pulling docker image docker:dind ...
ERROR: Preparation failed: Error response from daemon: toomanyrequests: You have reached your pull rate limit. You may increase the limit by authenticating and upgrading: https://www.docker.com/increase-rate-limit (docker.go:198:4s)
Will be retried in 3s ...
Using Docker executor with image harbor.XXX.XXX.net/library/docker_maven_jvm14 ...
Starting service docker:dind ...
Pulling docker image docker:dind ...
ERROR: Preparation failed: Error response from daemon: toomanyrequests: You have reached your pull rate limit. You may increase the limit by authenticating and upgrading: https://www.docker.com/increase-rate-limit (docker.go:198:3s)
Will be retried in 3s ...
ERROR: Job failed (system failure): Error response from daemon: toomanyrequests: You have reached your pull rate limit. You may increase the limit by authenticating and upgrading: https://www.docker.com/increase-rate-limit (docker.go:198:3s)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Another way:
If you don't want to add `daemon.json`, you can do this:

1. Pull docker-dind from docker hub

`docker pull docker:stable-dind`

2. Login to harbor

`docker login harbor.XXX.com`

3. Tag image to harbor

`docker tag docker:stable-dind harbor.XXX.com/library/docker:stable-dind`

4. Push to harbor

`docker push harbor.XXX.com/library/docker:stable-dind`

5. Go to the `.gitlab-ci.yml`
6. Instead of

```
services:
    - docker:dind
```

**write**:

```
services:
    
    - name: harbor.XXX.com/library/docker:stable-dind
      alias: docker
```

My `.gitlab-ci.yml` :

```
stages:
  - build_and_push

Build:
  image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY}/library/docker:ci_tools
  stage: build_and_push
  tags:
    - dind
  services:
    - name: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY}/library/docker:stable-dind
      alias: docker
  script:
    - docker login -u $DOCKER_REGISTRY_USERNAME -p $DOCKER_REGISTRY_PASSWORD $DOCKER_REGISTRY
    - make build test release REGISTRY=${DOCKER_REGISTRY}/library/ TELEGRAF_DOWNLOAD_URL="https://storage.XXX.com/ops/packages/telegraf-1.15.3_linux_amd64.tar.gz" TELEGRAF_SHA256="85a1ee372fb06921d09a345641bba5f3488d2db59a3fafa06f3f8c876523801d"
```

Comment: I had the same problem, instead of using Harbor, I have used GitLab Registry. Created a new repo named `Docker` and pushing there. Everything was ok, thanks for the procedure you've mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

I can't found the solution for Gitlab but you can tell the docker to ignore the docker hub registry and go to the local registry.

Add `daemon.json` in `/etc/docker/daemon.json`
, if doesn't exist you can simply add in the path.

> daemon.json

```
{
  "registry-mirrors": ["https://harbor.XXX.com"]
}
```

> sudo systemctl restart docker

Answer (score 1):

I too faced the same issue while deploying some micro-services to kube cluster, here is a blog that I wrote that provides a workaround to optimize the deployment workflow: https://mailazy.com/blog/optimize-docker-pull-gitlab-pipelines/